# Cannot GET /test - expressjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I want to load a log message when a user enters this URL address:

http://localhost:3000/test

but I get this error message: Cannot GET /test

This is my code:

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import App from './client/App';
import Html from './client/Html';
import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components'; // <-- importing ServerStyleSheet

var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");
const port = 3000;
const server = express();

const request = require('request');

server.get('/test', (req, res) => res.send('Hello  '));

server.get('/login', (req, res) => {

  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();

  const body = renderToString(sheet.collectStyles(<App />)); 
  const styles = sheet.getStyleTags(); 
  const title = 'Server side Rendering with Styled Components';
 console.log("hello!");
 request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("body") 
  }
});

  res.send(
    Html({
      body,
      styles, 
      title
    })
  );
});

server.listen(port);
console.log(`Serving at http://localhost:${port}`);
```

what is wrong with it? What am I missing?

My components version:

"express": "^4.14.0",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"request": "^2.88.0",

Comment: Please post your react code for index.js which has the routes configured..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
// init variables
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// routes to the specified path with the specified callback functions.
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
  console.log('Hello');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

> I want to load a log message when a user enters this url address:

Thats all you need.

Get more information [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).

Comment: That's not fundamentally different from what the OP has posted.

Comment: Keep it simple. With this code he can work forward step by step.